# Receiving 422 error sending a post request in Playwright - param is missing or the value is empty: data Did you mean? action attributes suite format

Tags: javascript, api, post, playwright

I'm trying to send a post request in a playwright test with the following:

```js
    const testSet = await request.post('https://url/sets.json', {
        data: {
            "type":"sets",

            "attributes":{
      
               "name":"DuaneDemo",
      
               "priority":"highest"
      
            },
            "instances":{

                "test-ids":[obj]
             }
        },
        headers: {
            'PTToken': 'token'
        }
    })
    const response = await (await testSet.json());
```

I'm getting the following error:

422 error sending a post request in Playwright - param is missing or the value is empty: data\nDid you mean?  action attributes suite format

When I run this post request in Postman it's successful.  Here's my postman body:

```js
{ "data": {
    "type":"sets",

    "attributes":{

        "name":"DuaneDemo",

        "priority":"highest"

    },
    "instances":{

        "test-ids":["9163455", "9163685"]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I think my formatting is wrong in my Playwright post but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct format:

```js
            data: {
                data: {
                    "type": "sets",

                    "attributes": {

                        "name": "DuaneDemo",

                        "priority": "highest"

                    },
                    "instances": {

                        "test-ids": [obj]
                    }
                }
            },
```